# Recursively clone submodules from GitHub using an access token

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have an umbrella repo containing a number of submodules. I am using

```
git clone --recurse-submodules --remote-submodules https://<access_token>@github.com/user/repo.git
```

to recursively clone all submodules. On Ubuntu, I am asked for the credentials of each submodule although they all can be accessed using the same access token, which I have tested by cloning them individually. Side note: I am asked for username and password, which have not been accepted anymore by GitHub since August, 13th.
On Windows, where Git was installed as part of Visual Studio, I only need to provide the access token once for the umbrella repo.

I already tried to use the Git credential cache, but that did not work:

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

How can I clone the submodules recursively with providing the access token only once?

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
git config --system credential.helper store
echo "https://username:token@github.com" > ~/.git-credentials
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/org/repo repo
```

Now cloning the main repo and submodules from github.com will use this token.

Comment: the sub-module still doesn't use the token