# Rewrite git submodule URLs during recursive clone

Tags: git

I'm cloning a project that contains *recursive* submodule with URLs of the form:

```
git@gitlab.company.com:project/repo.git
```

This works fine if you have an SSH key, however Gitlab CI instead uses an HTTP password. So instead you have to clone this URL:

```
https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.company.com/project/repo.git
```

That is fine for the top-level project (I just change the `git clone` command). It's even fine-ish for the first level of submodules (clone non-recursively, edit `.gitsubmodules`, update submodules).

But how an earth can you do this for *recursive* submodules?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72082137/7034621) is worth giving a shot?

Comment: I don't think that will help. As far as I understand it it just saves the HTTP username/password for later. But my problem is that the submodules are using SSH, not HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I was able to change `project/repo.git` to use relative submodule paths instead of absolute ones. Mercifully all of the subprojects already did this.